# React Native custom Progress Bar i need mathematical statement

Tags: javascript, react-native

i'm working on react native expo project, i'm trying to build custom ProgressBar, I have state call step if the step increase by 1 then the width value of the view has to increase, if the step decreases then the width value of the view has to decrease, so if the value increase or decrease it seems the view has some animation on it

```
const ProgressBar =({step , requset}) =>{

    const [ steps , setSteps ]= useState(0);
    const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState(null);
    const [ width , setWidth ] = useState(50);

    useEffect( ()=> {
        const getToken = async ()=>{ 
        const accessToken = await token.get();
          setAccessToken(accessToken)}

        getToken();
        accessToken  ?
             requset == 1 ?  setSteps(6) : setSteps(7)
             : setSteps(3)
     })

     useEffect (()=>{
        const newWidth =  (step*50);
        setWidth(newWidth);
     })

 
return(
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row',}} > 
     <View style={styles.progressBar}>
      <Animated.View 
      onLayout = {e =>{ 
         const newWidth = e.nativeEvent.layout.width;
         setWidth(newWidth);
    }}
      style ={ [styles.progress,{width: width}]}
      />
     </View>
     <Text style={styles.progressText}>{steps}/{step}</Text>
    </View>
)}
```

How can I make a mathematical statement that calculates the amount of width increases depend on Total steps?